# How to opendns on router with dynamic ip

Tags: dns, dynamic-ip, opendns

OpenDNS is almost completely useless with a dynamic ip and most people have dynamic ip addresses.

There isn't even a decent client for Linux to update your IP.

There is a script you can install but it only seems to update on startup and all my child needs to do is unplug and replug the cable from the wall or router and a new ip is created totally killing the opendns service .

I'm not even sure the Mac or windows ip update clients can protect from such a simple maneuver .

How can I get my ip address to constantly update with opendns, is my question.
We have several computers connected to the same wireless router.
I have entered the correct setup for the router but I need something to update the dynamic ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my question was worded better for my situation but here is the answer to my question.

https://askubuntu.com/a/48698/13177

The answer here by @pl1nk is actually the correct answer for the question at the link posted in this answer.

Confusing I know. It would be great if someone could switch the answers.

Again. The answer to my question is this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/48698/13177

And these are not duplicate questions, as my question is dealing with a home network on a router and this other question is dealing with a single computer.

Comment: Both links are same.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the dhcp configuration file `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`

And add this line:

`prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;`

This will prepend the OpenDNS nameservers with dynamic IP.

Comment: That will only make it work for that one computer but I'm trying to set it up for the network. I have already entered those numbers into the router but the problem is , when I want to use the opensns web filtering services, opendns needs to know my ip address . That address changes every time the connection is lost and has to be updated.

Comment: Downvote: this does not answer the question.